# Anyway to override a property in an application I don't have code for?

Tags: c#

I am using a C# 1.0 application that converts TIFFs to a new format, but I am trying to use it for something legacy - so the compression scheme it wants to use is not supported for what I'm doing.

The application wants to convert it to LZW, but I need it in JPEG compression.

I have used Reflector to see where in the code this property is set -is there a way for me to write an application that will change this property, via SPY or something, to what I need anytime it is set from within the application?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can use reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use reflector to decompile the code to the point that you see it, then you can just make your changes in the decompiled version and recompile it with visual studio.

Comment: I tried this, but I think it's obsfucated as there is all kinds of ambiguous properties that are making it very difficult to get a successful build out of.

Comment: @user53885: the only other things I can think of is: 1. contact the originator of that assembly and ask them.  or 2. write a new class that inherits from the existing one and just override the properties/methods you need.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to recompiling the code is to patch the IL. The [Reflexil plugin](http://reflexil.net/) for reflector simplifies the process. The homepage links to this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/msil/reflexil.aspx) on codeproject which gives some instructions. It appears the current version of reflexil (1.1) uses cecil 0.6 which should support .NET 1.0.

Seeing as LZW is lossless the result shouldn't be any worse if you did the conversion yourself but from your post I guess that is not an option?

Comment: Reflexil 1.1 uses Cecil 0.6 whereas Reflexil 1.2 uses Cecil 0.9.x